# Problem Starting Database Engine During & After the Installation : MS SQL Server 2019 on Windows 2019 Server

Tags: sql-server

[image]

> MS SQL Server 2019 (18.9.2) features

Hello,
I've tried to reinstall several times, I have always the database engine services failed. Please note that I've allowed the service through the firewall, no antivirus installed on my server. Also, on the sql server configuration manager, I've enabled the TCP/IP connections and started the MSSQLSERVER service manually, in vain.

Comment: Have you opened the ERRORLOG file yet to see what errors it is reporting. To find its location check the startup parameters of the SQL Server service (look for the `-e` parameter) and open that with Notepad or your favorite text editor to read its contents.

Comment: This is what my ERRORLOG shows:

Comment: The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DEV1 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos.
The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/DEV1:1433 ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos.

Comment: Part 3:The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
Service Broker manager has started.

Comment: Solved by creating a second ADMIN account, which is not the default Windows Administrator, with the same full admin privilege. Also, choosing mix authentication (Both sa & Admin).